# How to sum for 2 criteria over multiple values in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two categories: City and Product. I have sales for each of these over multiple weeks (10 weeks) and want to sum these for a specific city AND product.

I have tried using SUMIFS but this only works for one column of data and not for multiple weeks.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

For example:

I want to know sum of Melbourne and Dairy using one formula (so this should be 61 all up).

```
Category 1.   Category 2.  Week1     Week2     Week3
Melbourne     Dairy          10        20        5
Sydney        Fruit.         12.       6.        10
Brisbane      Fruit.         4.        8.        9
Melbourne     Fruit.         8.        7.        3
Melbourne     Dairy.         6.        9.        11
```

Comment: show an online version/pic of the data

Comment: ^^^^ better yet put the data as text in the Original Post using [edit] so we can copy paste instead of re-typing.

Comment: Try doing the `SUMIFS` statements at the bottom of each `Week` column, then summing the results.  Or adding a `Total` column and doing a `SUMIFS` on that

Comment: Yep, I can do that (i.e. create a total column and then add them up) but there should be a way where i can use one cell as a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

Array formula, so enter using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: or entered normally: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6=G2)*(B2:B6=H2)*(C2:E6))`. You beat me by a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: Can I also ask, why do we multiply? I.e. why use *? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ScottCraner - Yes that is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

A simple sumproduct should suffice.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$5=G2)*(B$2:B$5=H2)*C$2:D$5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but why do we multiply? I am struggling to understand why we do this

Comment: Multiplication is used to convert the boolean calculations from true/false to 1 and 0.